# How to call a tableview in a different view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

How can I share tableview between classes?

I actually created a tableview in a view controller (with xib file) and used following steps to make it disappear ...

```
[tableview retain];
[tableview removedfromsuperview];
```

According to my project, I created a new view controller (without xib file) and
now I want to recall the same tableview which was created in previous view controller.
I used something like this

```
Firstviewcontroller *firstviewcontroller=[[Firstviewcontroller alloc]init];
[self.view addsubview :firstviewcontroller->tableview ];
```

But it **didn't display table view** `firstviewcontroller`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can share the UI elements, but i'm sure you can replicate the table view.

**1.** Create the table view in the new controller.

**2.** Pass the array elements from the previous class (by using a singleton class or whatever suits your need.)

**3.** Populate the table view with the array passed from previous class. So that it looks similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you are creating new firstviewcontroller object. you should use the object which has the tableview.